# Configure URL in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dotnetnuke, virtual-directory

I have an existing DNN site set up in IIS and I want to link to another ASP.NET application in a separate folder. I want to maintain the same domain URL as follows:

http://dnn9.dnndev.me/otherapplication

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Currently, the main DNN site is set up as its own site in IIS (not under Default Web Site)., with its own App Pool. I tried adding a virtual directory to the main DNN site, pointing to the other application folder. It gives a 404. I added <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">  around the system.web section of the DNN site web.config. My main DNN site is set up as "dnn9.dnndev.me". I'm wondering if the "dnn9" subdomain on my local is causing an issue?

The other application is added as an application under Default Web Site in IIS, with its own App Pool.

I just created two test websites "Test1" and "Test2". I placed both of these under the "Default Web Site" node in IIS and added a virtual directory to Test1, pointing to Test 2 and it worked. So the main difference between this test scenario and my actual setup is that DNN is set up in IIS as a standalone app, not under the "Default Web Site" node in IIS.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Maybe look into "Virtual directories" within a site in IIS. Right click a site in IIS and it's listed there.

Comment: Do you mean within the site represented by the domain?

Comment: Yes. The url `otherapplication` points to a different folder on the server with a seperate app.

Comment: Right now the "other application' has its own AppPool and site in IIS. Should I remove these, add the virtual directory to the main site and point it to the other app folder?

Comment: I just tried this and am getting a 404 on the main site.

Comment: It can be difficult to get both sites running if they have large web.config like dnn. The virtual inherits settings and the apppool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to make the following scenario work.

1. DNN running in a website in IIS called "DNNDEV.ME" with the URL binding being set for DNNDEV.ME. Location of the DNN files c:\websites\dnndev.me
2. Created a new "APPLICATION" under the DNNDEV.ME site, using the same DNNDEV.ME application pool. I pointed that application's root to the folder c:\websites\newapp\
3. Modified the DNN web.config file to wrap <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> around the system.webServer node
4. With that functioning I added a file called sample.aspx, with the contents being

   This is a test.

The site loaded fine, and DNN continued to function as well. I added a sample web.config into the c:\websites\newapp\ folder from https://www.daniellittle.xyz/example-web-config-files-3-5-and-4-5/#Framework451 just to check that out, and the site continued to function as well.

I added dnn9.dnndev.me to my bindings on the DNNDEV.ME website as well, and it continues to function without problems.

Only real difference I can see from what I did, and you said you tested, is that I made an APPLICATION not a Virtual Directory in IIS for /NewApp/

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked! This is a migrated site from an older version - also had to remove httpmodules and httphandlers sections from DNN config file to get past YSOD errors.