# Configure WCF in Production IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, wcf-binding

I'm trying to expose my WCF service as part of my main site URL on a server. I have it working on the server (Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard) on IIS 8.5, but can only reach it locally with localhost, or using the machine name, as follows:

http://localhost/TeeSvc/Service1.svc

http://<<machinename>>.mysite.net/TeeSvc/Service1.svc

I have an existing site set up as follows:

http://mystaging.mysite.net

I need to be able to reach the service using:

http://mystaging.mysite.net/TeeSvc/Service1.svc

I saw an article [here](https://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/) dealing with this but it relates to an earlier version of IIS and I cannot get the cscript.exe console window to remain open long enough to issue any commands.

How can I go about this?

[image]

Comment: So the website under which you configured this WCF service is not the site of "http://mystaging.mysite.net"? Show your sites in IIS Manager, as that would save a thousand words.

Comment: Screenshot added. If you need image of a particular setting in IIS, let me know.

Comment: So I assume that `mystaging.mysite.net` is DNN9. Your options are just a few, 1) publish the WCF service under DNN9, then the URL should work. 2) Make IIS a reverse proxy and use rewrite rules to forward requests at `http://mystaging.mysite.net/TeeSvc/Service1.svc` to `http://localhost/TeeSvc/Service1.svc`.

Comment: When you say publish the service "under DNN9", do you mean remove service from under "Default Web Site" and add it as an application under DNN9? When trying this I get "Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetNuke.Professional' or one of its dependencies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by following the same approach in how to construct things in IIS, as outlined here:

[Configure URL in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651065/configure-url-in-iis)

My situation was further complicated by the fact that this was a migration of an older DNN site to version 9.2. There were a lot of unnecessary entries in the DNN web.config file; after I removed the httpHandlers and httpModules sections, I finally got it to work.